# Schema validation in JAX WW web service

Tags: web-services

I am developing web services using jax-ws and apache cxf with code first approach . I want to enable schema validation in my service . For this I have configured the cxf configuration file as follows

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="testService"
implementorClass="com.test.impl.TestServiceImpl"
implementor="#testServiceImpl"
 address="/testService">
<jaxws:serviceFactory>
<ref bean="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory"/>
 </jaxws:serviceFactory>
<jaxws:properties>
 <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true"/>
 </jaxws:properties>
 </jaxws:endpoint>

Service,

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT,use=SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL)

  public interface TestService {



 @WebMethod
String test(MyVo myVo) ;

}
```

MyVo,

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "MyVo")
    public class MyVo {

   @XmlElement(name = "name", required = true)
   private String name;

     ............. // getter and setter

     }
```

.

But after deploying the service wsdl looks like

```
      <xsd:complexType name="MyVo">
     <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />

     </xsd:sequence>
       </xsd:complexType>
```

As per documentation minOccurs should be 1 (because of required=true ) .

Also I am able to call service without setting name attribute in MyVo object . No error is coming from server.

I have created a endorsed directory in my jre\lib folder and jdk\lib folder and put jaxb-api-2.2.jar and jaxws-api-2.2.1.jar there . Still facing same problem . I am using jdk1.6.0_11.

Thanks

Please advice .

Comment: can some one provide solutions ?